# Windows Universal App browser with flash

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm looking for a way to display a browser with flash on a universal windows app. From what I can find, WebView doesn't load any plugins, so flash websites won't display. Anyone know of any solutions?

Comment: how about avoiding flash? it's effectively dead-man-walking technology. the sooner you ditch that garbage the better...

Comment: The problem is I'd like to display a website already created in flash inside a WebView. Unfortunately, avoiding flash will not work in this case.

Comment: Hi, Flash is not supported in the WebView. As Flash end of support is very close now, I doubt it will change. http://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2015/11/flash-html5-and-open-web-standards.html

Comment: There are a lot of flash to html 5 converters available

Comment: As it have already been said, there is no Flash support in WebView, and it probably will never change because of the near end of it. Also, WebView class should not be the primary thing of the app, it is here to be use time to time in the app, but not often. So you may want to change the way you have tought